# using a component in a plugin and calling method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to cake php and I have a plugin folder in my application

```
app/plugins
```

in plugin folder I have model and vendors folder. (Notice I dont have any view or controller folder)

```
app/plugins/model
app/plugins/vendors
```

I wanted to add a component to plugin folder so I added controllers folder to it and place my component file there.

```
app/plugins/controllers
app/plugins/controllers/myComp.php
```

The method in myComp.php is

```
class myCompComponent extends EmailComponent    {

    function hilpot() {
```

In my `vendors/shells/tasks` folder I have a file called my_test.php

In the file I have included the component like

```
var $components = array('myComp');
```

in the same file, i have a method that suppose to call the myComp method

```
function _Maikle()
    {

            $this->myComp->hilpot() = array(

 ...................
..................
```

And it fails at this point with the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::hilpot() in C:\wamp\www\folder\app\plugins\vendors\shells\my_test.php on line 87
```

Any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your plugin structure seems to be incorrect

```
/app/plugins/plugin_name/controllers/... etc
```

you probably didnt read the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1112/Creating-a-Plugin) at all. otherwise you would have notices this as well as that components are in a sub directory:

```
/app/plugins/plugin_name/controllers/components/...
```

also note that you should always include the pluginname:

```
var $components = array('PluginName.MyComp');
```

and m should be capitalized: MyComp